# Given a minimum polynomial for $\alpha$, find the minimum polynomial for $\alpha/3$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials, algebraic-numbers

Let $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+x+27$. Suppose $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfies $f(\alpha)=0$, and let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

1. Is $f(x)$ irreducible?
2. What is $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$?
3. What is $N_K(\alpha)$?
4. Is $\frac{\alpha}{3}\in\mathcal{O}_K$?
5. What is the minimum polynomial of $\frac{\alpha}{3}$?

---

I've answered all of these except for #5.
$f(x)$ is irreducible by taking $f$ mod $2$ and observing there are no linear factors (which suffices as $f$ is cubic). Since $f$ is irreducible, then $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$. By definition of the field polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^n(t-\sigma_i(\alpha))$ , $N_K(\alpha)=-27$. Since norms split over products, then $N_K(\frac{\alpha}{3})=\frac{1}{27}N_K(\alpha)=-1$, so $\frac{\alpha}{3}\in\mathcal{O}_K$.

---

What I thought about doing for #5 is to scale the original minimum polynomial appropriately using $\frac{\alpha}{3}$, i.e. $g(x)=27x^3+18x^2+3x+27$, but this cannot be correct as minimum polynomials are monic. I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your $g(x)$ and divide it by $27$, thereby getting $x^3+\frac23x^2+\frac19x+1$, and you're done!

Comment: But $\frac{0}{27}\neq0$... Kidding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And notice: even though the Norm of $\alpha/3$ is an integer, its minimal polynomial is not integral, so that $\alpha/3$ is *not* an algebraic integer.